# How to Add ID to Html.ActionLink - Same as You Would In HTML / CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a line of code in a .cshtml file:

`@Html.ActionLink("LION TECHNOLOGIES", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })`

You can see the text LION TECHNOLOGIES has been given a class of `navbar-brand`. Navbar-brand is a class in bootstrap.css, and I don't want to modify that file, so I'd like to assign LION TECHNOLOGIES an ID. How do I give LION TECHNOLOGIES an id `navbar-text`?

I tried this:

`@Html.ActionLink("LION TECHNOLOGIES", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand"}, new {@id = "navbar-text"})`

But it's giving me an error:

[image]

(when hovering over red underlined line)

`Argument 6: cannot convert from <anonymous type: string class>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions'`

I'm trying to link to my style.css file, where I'm trying to change to font-family for LION TECHNOLOGIES in the header. Style.css will look like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'plantagenet_cherokeeregular';
src: url('fonts/plantagenet_cherokee-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/plantagenet_cherokee-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

#navbar-text {
font-family: 'plantagenet_cherokeeregular';
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LION TECHNOLOGIES", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand", @id = "navbar-text"})
```

Comment: Yeah that did it. Thanks.